# How to fix normal map in unity

Tags: unity, 3d, shaders

[image]

hey, I'm just using unity, I'm having a problem with the normal map, like the picture above, if I use blender I just need to change the sRGB to non-color data, but when I import it to unity using the fbx format, why is the result like the picture above?  I've been looking for tutorials on YouTube but can't find the results, thank you

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1taEKN33XByWa-eFgzsyOpS3JYOltuYe9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It looks like your normal map contains information for just one side of the weapon, and the two halves have been unwrapped over one another, mirroring this data to the other side of the weapon. This can have a side effect of inverting the tangent space, making it look like the normal map is describing bumps on the *inside* of the surface, instead of the outside. If your 3D modelling software generates its tangents correctly, this should not be a problem - double-check that your export settings include tangent vectors.

Comment: [Here's a thread about this kind of issue](https://forum.unity.com/threads/symmetric-models-with-mirrored-normal-maps-shader-fix.65859/#post-420888). Also double-check that your normal map has been imported with the normal map type in its inspector.

Comment: I'm a little clueless, can you give me a practice video example?  I gave you the blender file

Comment: As I understand it, you mean that, I still haven't applied mirror modiffier?  or a problem with the uv that maybe the uv part is reversed but not the 3d part